# How do I write a file through my app in the Google App Engine to the Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: python, database, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, bucket

I am looking for a very simple way to create a file and write text data to it (I guess in my Google Cloud Platform bucket) through the app that I'm running in the Google App Engine. Which libraries/functions do I need to use in my code for doing this? I googled the crap out of this but I didn't find any easy ways to do it.

I'm a newcomer to coding, so if you provide code examples I would be very grateful! Thanks in advance :)

**Details**:
In the app, I'm scraping 250 webpages on another website every time a user wants to search something there. This, of course, produces extremely heavy loads on the server, not to mention that users have to wait for up to 45 seconds to see the results. To counteract this, I thought I'd set up a cron job which would scrape those webpages every 5 minutes or so and store their contents in a file somewhere (preferably 250 different files), which would later be accessed by the app during a search query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this library: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/functions

So something like this

```
import cloudstorage
with cloudstorage.open('/---bucket-name---/path/within/bucket/file.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(content)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: cloudstorage library is for python 3, right? My app uses 2.7 in standard environment :(

Comment: I'm using it with python 2.7, are you having trouble installing it?

Comment: Not anymore :D Thanks again!

Comment: Hey! If @Alex answer solved your problem, could you upvote/accept it ? So it can help more people in the future!